# Pure GWT Application As Spring Security Login

Tags: gwt, spring-security

How I can Use Pure GWT Login application in spring security , then after login redirect me to another GWT application.

Also if I have GWT Registration Application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example,

`http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html`

if you want to create login page with gwt components you have to use html. once user is valid user then you can redirect to your app.

Comment: but this example dose not use GWT Application as Login Page